# MKStorekit isFeaturePurchased returns NO after calling restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mkstorekit

I'm trying to implement a restore purchase button for a non-consumable product using the excellent MKStoreKit.

I've got the folliwing code on the restore button:

```
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete:^{
    [_priceLabel completeWithText:NSLocalizedString(@"App restored :)", @"")];

} onError:^(NSError *error) {
    [_priceLabel completeWithText:NSLocalizedString(@"Unable to restore", @"")];
}];
```

the completion block gets called correctly, but when I call

```
[MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"com.myapp.pro"]
```

I get a NO. Feel like I am missing something obvious?

Comment: I've just posted an answer to a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20964802/2880276) in case you're still wondering about this...

Comment: Thanks @JosephChen I actually gave up on MKStoreKit.. Good reference for others though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If yours is a subscription product, you should use isSubscriptionActive

Answer (score 0):

If this is in sandbox, which I assume it is - Apple actually expire subscriptions within about 30 seconds, even if they're supposed to last a month.

So initially you may get a that the subcription is active, but later (and by later I mean soon after), the answer will change from Apple.

Comment: it is not a subscription product